# Magento2: How to move short:description to more information

Tags: magento2

How to move short description to more information tab?
https://prnt.sc/t7dvyl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show `Short description` in More information Tab you need to set `short_description` attribute:

> **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront : Yes**

[image]

Above will add short description to Tab.

Now you need to remove default short description from its original position.

Create:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

with following content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope Above will help!